# Waiting for button to be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, coffeescript

I want to wait until one of the three buttons have been pressed successfully before running the next five statements. How can I do this?

```
playerTurn: (opponent) ->
    $attackButton.click -> buttonClick.attackButtonClick(opponent)

    $defendButton.click -> buttonClick.defendButtonClick(opponent)

    $useItemButton.click -> buttonClick.useItemButtonClick(opponent)

    status.Poison("opponent", opponent) if opponent.Poisoned
    status.Burn("opponent", opponent) if opponent.Burned
    status.Freeze("opponent", opponent) if opponent.Frozen
    opponent.undefend() if opponent.defenseDoubled or opponent.defenseTripled
    refresh(opponent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work for you to just wrap the statements in their own function and call it for each click?

```
playerTurn: (opponent) ->
  opponentAction = ->
    status.Poison "opponent", opponent  if opponent.Poisoned
    status.Burn "opponent", opponent  if opponent.Burned
    status.Freeze "opponent", opponent  if opponent.Frozen
    opponent.undefend()  if opponent.defenseDoubled or opponent.defenseTripled
    refresh opponent

  $attackButton.click ->
    opponentAction()
    buttonClick.attackButtonClick opponent

  $defendButton.click ->
    opponentAction()
    buttonClick.defendButtonClick opponent

  $useItemButton.click ->
    opponentAction()
    buttonClick.useItemButtonClick opponent
```

Comment: That works. May I ask why you have `return` at the end?

Comment: I was using a js/coffeescript converter (I don't do coffeescript too often). I think you actually don't need it there.